# AWS CDK Lookup one peered VPC in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-context

I have two VPCs(VPC_A, VPC_B) in two different accounts (AccountA, AccountB) and both VPCs are peered successfully. I have CDK code that has a pipeline stage to deploy to AccountA. I have a need to lookup VPC_B from AccountA's context and lookup & modify security group which is in VPC_B. I have below code written, but it's not working. When I do cdk synth, it gives me an error saying it cannot find VPC_B in AccountA's context.

```
const vpcB: IVpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'VPC_B', {
        vpcId: 'VPC_B_ID'
    });

    const SG_B: ISecurityGroup = ec2.SecurityGroup.fromLookupByName(
        this,
        'SG-B',
        'SG-B_ID,
        vpcB
    );
```

Here is the synth step in CodePipeline

```
            synthCodeBuildDefaults: {
            rolePolicy: [
                new PolicyStatement({
                    actions: ["sts:AssumeRole"],
                    effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                    resources: [
                        'lookup_role_arn_for_account_a
                    ],
                }),
            ]
        }
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. My suggestion for you is to create another stack on the AccountB and do whatever you want there, separate from AccountA stack.

There was even an issue on their repo about this:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/12754#issuecomment-769786855